# Validator for ListView Selection Model?

Tags: java, validation, javafx, controlsfx

I'm trying to make it so a selection is required in order to proceed and I am wondering if it is possible to achieve this using the ControlsFX Validator and ValidationSupport.

```
public static void test(ValidationSupport support, ListView listView) {
    Validator<ObservableListWrapper> validator = (control, value) -> {
        boolean condition = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() == null;
        return ValidationResult.fromMessageIf(control, "Please select an item", Severity.ERROR, condition);
    };
    support.registerValidator(listView, true, validator);
}
```

This does not work. Selecting an item on the list does not seem to effect this in any way. I am thinking this is because I'm using the listView parameter instead of the value one, but I do not know how to get the value one to correspond with the list view's selection model.

Answer (score 0):

`ValidationSupport` uses `ValueExtractor` to extract an observable value which when changes a revalidation will be made. `ValueExtractor` uses `ListView#itemsProperty` as default for all `ListView`s, which means that `ValidationSupport` will revalidate only when `itemsProperty` is changed.
In order to change this for all instances of `ListView`, you can set an observable value extractor using the static method `addObservableValueExtractor` like this:

```java
ValueExtractor.addObservableValueExtractor(c -> c instanceof ListView, 
        c -> ((ListView) c).getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty());
```

If you want to change it for a specific instance of `ListView` you can try doing this:

```java
ValueExtractor.addObservableValueExtractor(c -> c == listView, 
        c -> ((ListView) c).getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty());
```

An example using `ListView<File>`:

```java
ListView<File> listView = new ListView<>();
ValidationSupport support = new ValidationSupport();
ValueExtractor.addObservableValueExtractor(c -> c == listView,
        c -> ((ListView<File>) c).getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty());
Validator<File> validator = new Validator<>() {
    @Override
    public ValidationResult apply(Control control, File file) {
        boolean condition = file == null;
        return ValidationResult.fromMessageIf(control, "Please select a file", Severity.ERROR, condition);
    }
};
support.registerValidator(listView, true, validator);
```